# Angular Nesting Multiple Click Directives

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have two directives one is contained within a view, the other is applied to the view's container.

```
<div id="content" data-panel='{{ pNav }}' close-content>
    <div class="inner reveal-animation" ng-view>

    </div>
</div>
```

Markup loaded inside ng-view:

```
<div class="inner-content services">
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2 general-content">
            <h1>Our Services</h1>
            <ul class="tab-nav">
                <li><a href="" class="cx" tab-content><span>AB</span> Customer Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="" class="bx" tab-content><span>CD</span> Existing Applciations</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content">

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Application Directives:

```
  myApp.directive('closeContent',['PanelServ', function(PanelServ){

  return function(scope, element, attrs){

    element.on('click', function(){
     });

  };

}]);

myApp.directive('tabContent',['PanelServ', function(PanelServ){

    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.on('click', function () {
            console.log(element);
        });
    };
}]);
```

When clicking the anchor tags with the tab-content directive, the tab content directive fires and it is immediately followed by the execution of the close-content directive.

Is there something I should include within the tab-content directive to prevent the close-content directive from firing when the tab-content directive is executed?

Is this not how angular is designed to interpret these interactions?  Can someone point me toward a resource to obtain a better understanding of what I'm attempting to accomplish.

Any enlightenment would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

This is called `event bubbling`. The event triggered on the HTML element is first handled on the element itself and then is propagated to the parent elements upon the DOM tree - thus firing the event handlers of the parent elements.

AngularJS has nothing to do with this, it is how Javascript events work.

To stop the propagation in your case use `stopPropagation()` method on the `event` object passed into the handler:

```
myApp.directive('tabContent',['PanelServ', function(PanelServ){
    return function(scope, element, attrs){
        element.on('click', function (event) {
            event.stopPropagation();
            console.log(element);
        });
    };
}]);
```

This will prevent the execution of the `closeContent` directive's click handler.